# Using the same base class where some classes only need a subset of the base properties

Tags: c#

I am writing a class library to model a car. I have a base class called "Dimension", which provides the properties/methods for measurements of the cars (Eg length, width, etc). This is for the entire car in general.

However, I need to provide dimensions on individual parts too (E.g. wheels). Wheels, for example, only use a subset of the information. Eg the width, and not every readily available property. Does it make sense to use the same base class for this or do I need to look into something more sophisticated to model this accurately?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use it for Wheels too. Even if the wheel will have the same width as height it stil HAVE the width and height... You should just ensure that width is copied into height to be precise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Car *has* Dimension; a Car is not a subclass of Dimension.
By making Car inherit from Dimension you are squandering the only available inheritance slot available to you in C#.

There is little benefit to be had from using inheritance to share properties amongst concrete subclasses, especially now that C# has things like automatic properties to save typing. Better to save your inheritance slot for some future requirement.

I would suggest instead giving the Car object properties to define the dimensions as appropriate, and perhaps have it (and Wheel) implement an interface, say IDimension, to allow you to treat Car and Wheel polymorphically if you want to write code that can be applied to any objects that have dimensions:

[image]

Comment: +1 because this is sound logic.  However, I do think it's okay to put 'has a' members in the base when you know that every subclass will always have those members.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good design. Do car and wheel derive from IDimension in this case? My uml is really poor but given the box design for both types above, I assume so.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the base class with only the properties that are shared by all the children and then add as needed. I had a similar issue and in my first draft did what you did. After I had finished a lot of my application I broke it down and rewrote most of it so the base class had just what was necessary and then added on as needed. I think first method is a lot quicker and when you have time you can go back and make it all nice and pretty.

Answer (score 0):

If everything has dimensions then put it in your base class, if not then use an interface.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense for the base class  to only contain methods or properties that are common between all derived classes. If you find that a subset of children also contain some similar properties it may also be worth creating a second base class which is derived from the first. I usually end up with a set up of an interface which a few base classes implement followed by a number of concrete classes.

Though granted this may not be visible always at time of coding. I always find refactoring code good practice near the end of the code completion.

Though in your case dimension may not be the best base class. It may be worth using a dimension interface instead to allow car to extend from a different class if needed.